# Алгоритм сортировки слиянием(C#)

Tags: c#

Отсмотрел я значит вот такую лекцию по этому Алгоритму(на питоне правда но как я понял сути дела не меняет по крайней мере для функции слияния двух массивов)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf82-r9hl2Y&list=PLRDzFCPr95fK7tr47883DFUbm4GeOjjc0&index=9
начало где-то с 3 минуты и там вроде всё понятно,но мне неясно что происходит в памяти когда мы начинаем рекурсивно вызывать функцию для того чтобы раздробить массив до одного элемента, смотрел реализации этого алгоритма в интернете как-то тоже несильно помогло, затем наткнулся на такой ролик
https://youtu.be/RZK6KVpaT3I?list=PLM-oHmQfcFEIlBMEMf28CnVbeY4rQgswj
Но мне почему-то ещё не ясно что зачем как и почему.
Объясните на примере языка C# если можно

Comment: В вопросе отсутствует конкретика в явном виде. Ссылочные вопросы не приветствуются.

Comment: Мне кажется что вот тут http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC хорошо обьяснено. На с# переписать... ну... возможно, прийдется правда ссылки по заменять на массивы.

Comment: @nick_n_a попробую уточнить специально для вас. 
Как именно происодит дробление массива на под массивы и что твориться в памяти, в втором видео что я скинул есть попытка прояснить этот момент, но мне всё равно не ясно

Comment: *Как именно происодит дробление* - Методом половинного деления. Находится середина, и массив разрезается пополам. Пункт 1, из ссылки википедии. Почитайте материал по-ссылке.

Comment: @nick_n_a скажите вы смотрели второе видео, там всего пять минут глянуть и можно понять мой вопрос, то что массив половиниться это и дураку понятно,я конкретно спросил как он делиться(да тут вы ответили), а второе что будет происходить в памяти(здесь вы решили забить на самую важную часть для понимания)

Comment: Что будет происходить в памяти - зависит от конкретной реализации как и в  любом другом алгоритме. Ну кроме тривиальных квадратичных, не использующих доп. память для своей работы.

Comment: Почему бы не прочитать объяснение метода, и если останутся вопросы - спросить со ссылкой на текст?